# Kerning doesn't work in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, kerning

I created a custom font, and wanted to use it in Illustrator. However, some of the kerning was not working. Most of the kerning works, but there are some that doesn't. I've tried the font on MS Word and Powerpoint, and the kerning works perfectly on those programs. I've tried deleting the preference but that did nothing.

How can I get the kerning to work on my custom font?

EDIT: Thanks for all the response! Here are some of the information that might help resolving the issue... 
I'm a complete newb when it comes to making fonts, so the problem is most likely in the font file.Also, should I upload my font?

I use illustrator CC 2017

⋅illustrators kerning settings are set to automatic

⋅*as a work-around for a problem in after effects* all spacing between letters are handled by kerning

⋅created using fontlab studio 5, but also tried importing the project to fontlab VI preview and then generating the font(both had the same problem)

⋅most of the kerning is done by class kerning

⋅done by following the tutorial here:
https://youtu.be/UhDMmIJE-BQ
https://youtu.be/P0C4oVSBOQg

⋅.ttf file format

Edit2:it was a problem with my font.. some of the characters were included in the classes more than once. thanks!

Comment: "some of the kerning was not working" - how so? What letter pairings? We need more info to help at all

Comment: Which font editor? How did you define in that font editor the kerning to be in use?

Comment: This is actually hard to answer, for example maybe your kerning in language specific and illustrator is set to a different language. Maybe you have enabled a stylistic set. Maybe office over compensates, or you have set optical kerning in illustrator and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe and Microsoft handle kerning completly differently from each other.  I haven't looked into how kerning is handled by Microsoft programs, but typically when you run into issues like this with a Microsoft program, it is because something behind the scenes in the Microsoft program is trying to fix a problem for you.  A perfect example is when you are using a typeface that uses regular, demi, medium, strong, etc., instead of bold.  If you have text set in regular, and you apply "bold" to it in MS Word, it will create a "bold" version of the regular typeface, rather than using one of the bolder options that exist in that typeface.

An Adobe product, on the other hand, will give you an error message, telling you that there is no "bold" option for that particular typeface, and you have to manually change it to medium or strong.

I think that @user287001 is onto something when s/he asked how you defined the kerning within the font editor you used to create a font.  I think that Illustrator probably relies more on the internal kerning information than the Microsoft programs, and it may be looking for more detail than you put into your font when you created it.

I found [this article](https://www.fontshop.com/content/adventures-in-space-kerning) that talks about the differences between Metrics and Optical kerning in Adobe products.  It focuses on InDesign, but also shows examples for Illustrator.  Check it out and see if it is helpful.  I also suggest looking for articles that talk about how your specific version of Illustrator handles contextual controls (which include items like character alternates, ligatures, etc.).  There have been quite a few changes to this functionality in recent Adobe upgrades.